# PDO и Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: php, pdo

Добрый день! не могу понять что вызывает данную ошибку, проверил запрос несколько раз, но вроде все верно:

```
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('UPDATE orders SET 
name=:name,
second_name=:second_name,
family=:family,
date_birth=:date_birth,
phone=:phone,
email:=email,
doctor_type=:doctor_type,
doctor_id=:doctor_id,
price=:price,
cost_method=:cost_method,
cashback=:cashback,
active=:active,
accepted=:accepted,
comment=:comment,
street=:street,
house=:house,
house_gate=:house_gate,
flat=:flat,
fr=:fr,
ekg=:ekg,
ekg_w_scr=:ekg_w_scr  
WHERE id=:id');
$stmt->execute(array('name'=>$descr_array['name'],
'second_name'=>$descr_array['second_name'],
'family'=>$descr_array['family'],
'date_birth'=>$descr_array['date_birth'],
'phone'=>$descr_array['phone'],
'email'=>$descr_array['email'],
'doctor_type'=>$descr_array['doctor_type'],
'doctor_id'=>$descr_array['doctor_id'],
'price'=>$descr_array['cost'],
'cost_method'=>$descr_array['cost_method'], 
'cashback'=>$cashback,
'active'=>$active,
'accepted'=>$accepted,
'comment'=> $comment,
'street'=>$descr_array['street'],
'house'=> $descr_array['build'],
'house_gate'=> $descr_array['build_gate'],
'flat'=>$descr_array['flat'],
'ekg'=> $ekg,
'ekg_w_scr'=> $ekg_w_scr,
'fr'=>$fr,
'id'=>$descr_array['id_order']   ));
```

Отформатировал данным образом чтобы было удобней искать проблему...

Comment: свежий взгляд показывает: `email:=email,`

Comment: ... Спасибо! невнимательность...